# angular js UI Router sending params in URL

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a state in my config.js which looks like this:

```
            state("link_redirect", {
                url: "/link-redirect/",
                controller: "LinkRedirectCtrl",
                title: "Redirect Link",
                params: {endpoint: null}
            });
```

I dont want to change the state definition in shown above, still how can I send the `endpoint` params in URL so that I can fetch it using $stateParams service in my controller ?

Comment: If you want something to be accessible to `$stateParams` you will need to add it to your url like this: `url: "/link-redirect/:endpoint"`

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to access state params. Send as your state definition

```
   state("link_redirect", {
            url: "/link-redirect",
            controller: "LinkRedirectCtrl",
            title: "Redirect Link",
            params: {endpoint: null}
        });
```

Access them like, `$stateParams.params.endpoint`

But if you want your `endpoint` visible in URL, you must send like

```
   url: "/link-redirect/:endpoint"
```

Remove `params: {endpoint: null}`

and access it like this  `$stateParams.endpoint`

Comment: are you sure when we have params: {endpoint: null}, we need to access like $stateParams.params.endpoint and not like $stateParams.endpoint

Comment: Yeah, I am sure. You can try and check. Where the `params` is the object we are passing.